# Fill shape with asterisks

Tags: c, shapes, eof

I wrote a program to fill in closed figures with asterisks.

For some reason it isn't accepting the sentinel value `EOF` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Why is this?

```c
#include "usefunc.h"

#define height 100
#define width 100

void showRow(int numbers[], int size_numbers) {
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for (i = 0; i &lt; size_numbers-3; i++) {
        printf("%c, ", numbers[i]);
  }
    printf("%c ]", numbers[size_numbers-3]);
    printf("\n");
}

void showshape(int shape[][width], int lines, int max_buf) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i &lt; lines; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j &lt; max_buf; j++) {
            printf("%c", shape[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fill(int row[][width], int rownum, int end) {
    int i, c = 1, inside = 0;
    for (i = 0; i &lt; end; i++) {
        if (row[rownum][i] == '*') {
            c++;
        }
        if (!(c%2)) inside = 1;
        else inside = 0;
        if (inside) {
            row[rownum][i] = '*';
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int shape[height][width], i = 0, j = 0, lines = 0;
    int sentinel = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (sentinel != EOF) {
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
            sentinel = temp;
            shape[i][j] = temp;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        lines++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i &lt; lines; i++) {
        fill(shape, i, width);
    }
    fill(shape, 0, j);
    //for (i = 0; i &lt; lines; i++)
    showshape(shape, lines, j+2);
}
```

---

**Edit 1**

Just updated the code. It doesn't quite print the box. what's going on?

---

**Edit 2**

Another update. This time I'm copying the value of temp, however I get

> ```
> Bus error
> ```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please ignore the backticks around the shape[][] part in main()

Comment: Mind what Neil said. In a implementation where `char` is unsigned it will never, ever equal EOF.

Comment: got that, did change it.

Comment: After the edit: you really shouldn't call `getchar()` twice in a row like that. You will lose characters (the first one, in `sentinel`, is completely ignored).

Comment: whoa thank you...! how do you advise i fix this? your solution has the same problems as mine. lines of `*`s

Comment: possible duplicate of [filling in a shape with C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185567/filling-in-a-shape-with-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
int temp;
```

EOF is an integer value, not a char.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. however, the problem remains. after hitting Ctrl-D the program does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
    shape`[i][j]` = temp;
    j++;
}
```

I suspect this this never exits once `EOF` is reached. I mean, `getchar` probably continues to throw `EOF` at you and you ask "Not `\n` ? Okay, no need to stop".

Also, what @Neil Butterworth said in his answer is *really sensible*.

Comment: +1 : the idom is `while (((temp = getchar()) != '\n') && (temp != EOF)) { /* ... */ }` (possibly with not so many parenthesis as I use)

Comment: @tekknolagi: I suspect you're writing past the end of the array `shape`. Your `while` loop is still wrong and never ends. Inside the loop you keep incrementing `j` and assign `temp` (probably EOF) to `shape[0][j]`, but `shape[0][100]` is invalid (though it probably doesn't error -- `shape[0][10000]` (or soon afterwards) will definitely error though)